# Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#

When i try to run a project using this dll. i get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=90ba9c70f846762e' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've tried all possible combinations of these properties:

[image: Project properties]

Also tried re-adding the reference.
There are two projects in the solution, the reference is in both (if that info is of any use).

It's a C#, .NET 4 project.

What is causing the error?

Comment: Have you tried copying the mentioned dll into your Output Directory?

Comment: When I get this error it's usually because I added a reference to a DLL to my project, then updated the physical DLL to a different version. Try removing the reference to 'Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell' and then re-adding it with your current file

Comment: @Matt I did so. Still no luck.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: @Daniel Schlößer this seems to do it. I cannot understand why would it not copy itself? It is inside a folder i usually call _Assemblies_. It only works if inside the root directory of the executable. The main project does not directly use it, but references another project that does.

Comment: You can try to fix it by expanding the Project references, rightclicking the mentioned assembly and select properties. There you can set "Local copy" to true. Then this dll will be copied to the Output Directory autmatically during build.

Comment: @DanielSchlößer 7 years later and this is still google's top result, unfortunately neither of the suggestions identified worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

even MS package gives the same error, I did install this one  https://github.com/contre/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1 and it worked perfectly

[image]

Comment: Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell v1.1.4 by rpastric, contre, dahall, in my case works perfect with .Net 6 desktop app

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually a solution so solved the error. But I found an alternative package that works well:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it by setting the default folder path, like so:

```
CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
dialog.InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for JJ_Jason, but I believe I was receiving this error because I was using the wrong Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.

There are three:

1: Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell, authored by Microsoft

2: Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell, authored by Lischee

3: Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack.Shell, authored by rpastric

I was receiving this error with the Lischee version of the package but when I switched over to the Microsoft version, the issue went away. I'm assuming Malior and BigOmar had the same issue but in reverse.

Comment: 4: so far newest seems is Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell v1.1.4 by rpastric, contre, dahall, in my case works perfect with .Net 6 desktop app