# Programming in Visual Studio C# Windows Forms and including a NuGet package; How do I find out the namespace to reference?

Tags: c#, forms, namespaces, nuget

I was browsing this topic [Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724551/microsoft-windowsapicodepack-shell-could-not-load-file-or-assembly) because my program got this error window on someone else's computer:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTFBP.png)

So I installed a different package from NuGet, the WindowsApiCodePack made by rpastric for testing. Only problem is, I have no idea how to reference the namespace in code. For the Windows official pack it was:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;
```

How do I find out what namespace I have to use for a NuGet Package?

Comment: Does it run locally but doesn't run on another computer?  If Yes, you could try to publish your app and set  the Deployment mode to be "Self-contained"

Comment: Thanks, I have never published an app before and am now in the process of figuring out how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Visual Studio menu: View > Object Browser. Look down the treeview on the left, it will show you the various namespaces. Click to open the namespaces to explore further.

[image: Object browser showing namespaces]